# Download multiple files selected with MVC5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing a view in MVC5 that looks like this:

[image]

I need to select one or more records of the table and to be able to download the previously saved files, in the database. I have been looking for a solution and done several tests, but I can not find a solution. I was trying to send from javascript the selected codes to the controller and download the documents from the same, but I could not do it. The download could be in case you can, taking all the files and generating a zip, or automatically downloading all to the default folder of the browser.
  I would greatly appreciate anyone who can help me ... Greetings!

this is my ajax call:

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/GestionGarantias/Garantias/Download",
            data: { pCodigo: mCodigo },//Here I would send the list of //codes, but now to test, I only call the controller regardless of the value, //because the values in the list set them in the handy controller to test.
            xhrFields: {
                responseType: 'blob'
            },
            success: function (data) { //Here should I bring a zip with all files supposedly?
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
                a.href = url;
                a.download = 'myfile.zip'; //------------------> I UNDERSTAND THAT THIS IS THE NAME THAT WE SHOULD INDICATE FOR Download ... is it so?
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            },
            error: function (request, status, errorThrown) {
                //alert("Se produjo un error al descargar los adjuntos.");
            }
        });
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Download(List<String> codes)
        {
            codes = new List<string>();
            codes.Add("1079");
            codes.Add("1078");
            codes.Add("1077");
            MemoryStream ms = null;

            foreach (string codigoGar in codes)
            {
                string mimetypeOfFile = "";
                Garantias oGarantia = ControladorGarantias.getGarantia(SessionHelper.GetEntorno(), codigoGar);
                var stream = new MemoryStream(oGarantia.comprobante);
                ms = new MemoryStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                if (stream.Length >= 256)
                    stream.Read(buffer, 0, 256);
                else
                    stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);

                try
                {
                    System.UInt32 mimetype;
                    FindMimeFromData(0, null, buffer, 256, null, 0, out mimetype, 0);
                    System.IntPtr mimeTypePtr = new IntPtr(mimetype);
                    mimetypeOfFile = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeTypePtr);
                    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeTypePtr);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                string fileName = "";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mimetypeOfFile))
                {
                    switch (mimetypeOfFile.ToLower())
                    {
                        case "application/pdf":
                            fileName = "Comprobante_" + oGarantia.nombreService + "_" + oGarantia.nroFactura + ".pdf";
                            break;
                        case "image/x-png":
                            fileName = "Comprobante_" + oGarantia.nombreService + "_" + oGarantia.nroFactura + ".png";
                            break;
                        case "image/pjpeg":
                            fileName = "Comprobante_" + oGarantia.nombreService + "_" + oGarantia.nroFactura + ".jpg";
                            break;
                    }
                }
                using (var zip = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    var entry = zip.CreateEntry(fileName);
                    using (var fileStream = stream)
                    using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                    {
                        fileStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                    }
                }
            }
            return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip");
        }
```

what I do is create a list in it, just for testing.
My idea is for each of the records selected in the table, find their information, (file) and add them to the zip.

What am I doing wrong? thank you very much! And forgiveness for ignorance.

Comment: I keep the documents as varbinary in the database.

Comment: Palaco - I have added an answer to your question..U can use the function but for this u need stream data

Answer (score 8):

There's two pieces to your question. First, there's the issue of getting all the files, and second there's the issue of downloading them. Before we tackle these, let's take a step back and realize how the request-response cycle works.

With HTTP a client makes a request and the server returns a response. Importantly, there is an exact 1-1 correlation here. A request can have one and only one response. This means that if you need to provide multiple files as a download, you *have* to zip them up, as you can only return one file, not multiple. Creating a zip file allows you to return just one file, while still satisfying the requirement of allowing the user to download all the files at once.

Then there's the issue of AJAX. The `XMLHttpRequest` object in JavaScript is essentially a thin client. It makes HTTP requests and receives responses, but that's it. Unlike with requests made by the web browser when navigation through the address bar, nothing is done with the response automatically, that is on you, as the developer to handle the response and actually make something happen.

With that out of the way, the first part is creating an action that can return a zip file as a response. This is actually pretty straight-forward: you just need to return a `FileResult`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DownloadCodes(List<int> codes)
{
    // use codes to get the appropriate files, however you do that

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            // write zip archive entries
        }

        return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip");
    }
}
```

For the writing of the zip archive entries, it depends on where the file data is coming from. If you've got filesystem references, you'd just do:

```
zip.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file));
```

If you have byte arrays, such as what you'd get back from a varbinary column in a DB:

```
var entry = zip.CreateEntry(file.Name);
using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream(file.Data))
using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
{
    fileStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
}
```

Where `file.Name` and `file.Data` are made up properties referring to where you store the filename and where you store the file data, respectively.

Now, you can simply do a normal form post to this action, and since the response is a file type not viewable in a web browser (zip archive), the browser will automatically prompt a download. Additionally, since this is not viewable in a browser, the actual view in your tab/window will not change either, negating the normal need to use AJAX to accomplish staying on the same page. However, you can use AJAX if you want, but you will only be able to handle a file response in AJAX in modern browsers (basically anything but IE 10 or less). If you don't need to support older versions of IE, then the code you need would be something like:

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/url/to/download/code/action',
    data: data // where `data` is what you're posting, i.e. the list of codes
    xhrFields: {
        responseType: 'blob'
    },
    success: function (data) {
        // handle file download
    }
});
```

**Plain JavaScript**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function () {
    var data = xhr.response;
    // handle file download
}
xhr.open('POST', '/url/to/download/codes/action');
xhr.send();
```

Whichever path you take, the code for handling the file download is:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
a.href = url;
a.download = 'myfile.pdf';
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the contribution, I will try this solution, I will try to do it this way.

Comment: This code I do for each of the codes corresponding to my files in a foreach. My question is the following, it is assumed that for each of the records, I will create a zip file, or I will include each one within one, because that is what I need, create a zip, and inside, each one of The files obtained from the list previously passed.

Comment: using (var zip = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    var entry = zip.CreateEntry(fileName);
                    using (var fileStream = stream)
                    using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                    {
                        fileStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                    }
                }

Comment: The code for writing the entry would go where I added the `// write zip archive entries` comment, which is *inside* the for loop.

Comment: A thousand excuses Chris, is that I lack so little, and I think that you have given me what I need, I manage to generate the .rar file with the files inside, but when I try to open them after de-scrambling the file, it's as if the files were damaged, I opened the applications for each file type, but did not show me the content, any ideas? How can I show you my methods? Is that I am new to the page. Maybe a mail?

Comment: First, I'm a little confused. The code here creates a *ZIP* file. How did you get a RAR? You'd have to use a special C# library for that, if such a one exists in the first place. If you just tried to return the result of this code as file ending with `.rar`, then that would explain the corruption. Short of that, yes, you should open a new question of Stack Overflow with your current code, specifically relating to this new issue.

Comment: FWIW, Looks like there is indeed RAR-supporting compression libraries for C#, but it's still unclear if you're actually using one of those.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I say that I can get the .zip file, with the other files inside, but when I open them, it's as if they are corrupted, these can be of type image, pdf, when I unzip the zip, the files are correct with their Extensions, but when opening them, it only opens the program associated with the extension and tells me that it can not be opened.

Comment: Well, this soft of works for me. I can extract from 7-zip, but not from windows default.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following class to download file:

```
public class FileDownloadResult : ContentResult
{
    private string fileName;
    private Stream fileData;
    private bool downloadFlag;
    public FileDownloadResult(string fileName, Stream fileData, bool downloadFlag)
    {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.fileData = fileData;
        this.downloadFlag = downloadFlag;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.fileName))
            throw new Exception("A file name is required.");
        if (this.fileData == null)
            throw new Exception("File data is required.");
        var contentDisposition = "";
        if (!downloadFlag)
            contentDisposition = string.Format("inline; filename={0}", this.fileName);
        else
            contentDisposition = string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", this.fileName);
        context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition);


        if (downloadFlag)
            ContentType = "application/force-download";
        else
        {
            if (this.fileName.IndexOf(".pdf", fileName.IndexOf(".")) > 0)
                ContentType = "application/pdf";
            else if (this.fileName.IndexOf(".csv", fileName.IndexOf(".")) > 0)
                ContentType = "application/csv";
            else if (this.fileName.IndexOf(".xls", fileName.IndexOf(".")) > 0)
                ContentType = "application/xls";
            else if (this.fileName.IndexOf(".xlsx", fileName.IndexOf(".")) > 0)
                ContentType = "application/xslx";
            else
                ContentType = "application/txt";
        }
        context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", ContentType);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];


        int count = 0;
        while ((count = fileData.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            context.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your controller, use like:

```
public FileDownloadResult Download(string fileName, Stream fileStream)
{
     return new FileDownloadResult(fileName, fileStream, true);
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much Muhammad Qasim, I will try your solution and then I will comment.

Comment: @SebaPalacio - You are welcome. Please do let me know if this solves your problem and mark it as answer and upvote if it helped you :)

Comment: Thanks for the help partner, I do not work for multiple files, but anyway thank you, or maybe I do not know how to implement that code, Chris, was closer to what I wanted, manage to compress zip files with their code and download the Zip, but after decompressing this zip, the files are corrupt, I do not understand why. Anyway, thank you very much to both!

Answer (score 0):

I took from @Chris Pratt and had to make some changes to make it work for me

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
           // write zip archive entries
           zip.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file), CompressionLevel.Optimal);
         }

     }
     return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip");
}
```